# javascript get all key with values of an array of object as array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I get all keys with values of an array of objects as an array?

For example I want to have all the src keys as array for an assetloader:

```
images = [
    {"name":"an image","src":"http://source.png"},
    {"name":"an image2","src":"http://source2.png"},
    {"name":"an image3","src":"http://source3.png"}
];

//the solution code here..

console.log(solution); 

// Output:
// ["http://source.png", "http://source.png2","http://source3.png"]
```

I can loop through the images array and push all the 'src' tags into the solution var, but I think this is not an good practise in terms of performance.

Also I can't use the original image.src tag, the assetloader is from an framework and accepts only an array with sources.

Comment: Why do you think that? And what kind of code do you expect a solution to show if not exactly what you describe?

Comment: Lets say I have an array of 10,000 images. I think that will draw performance to convert all the images to an array of images.src

Comment: You can't loop through an array without actually *looping through the array*.

Comment: @Ismail: Yeah, it will take some time (very, very little time to be exact). But you can't make an omelette without breaking any eggs.

Comment: @Jon True, but I think there is an better solution to this.

Comment: @Ismail: Have you profiled it? No algorithm here is going to do better than O(n) because you have to hit *every* entry of `images` at some point.

Comment: Can't you just use the original images array instead of (partially) duplicating it? This should save the most of the overhead you worry about.

Comment: So 'scratch when itch': build the sources array as suggested here; there might be no actual performance issue as long as you have so few images that the assetloader can easily load them... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

you can use native `map` function for this.

```
var solution = images.map(function (img) {
    return img.src;
})
console.log(solution);
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner for Mritunjay's answer

```
images.map((i) => i.src)
```